# Bash: Custom sort / for each ID group, move a certain line to top of group

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, match, move

I have an 8-column file, and the first two columns are IDs.  The IDs in the first column repeat up to twelve 12 times.  I need to iterate by the first column ID, and when I find the row in which col1=col2 I need to move this row to the top of that ID group.  One complication is that the matching part is only one piece of column 1 ID and column 2 IDs. The file is already sorted.  Here's a sample of the input:

```
aac(3)-IIa_1_X51534     lcl|JQ364967.1_cds_AFI72859.1_82        99.768 
aac(3)-IIa_1_X51534     lcl|X51534.1_cds_CAA35913.1_1   100.000    
aac(3)-IIa_1_X51534     lcl|EU022315.1_cds_ABS70978.1_1 99.535 
aac(6')-33_1_GQ337064   lcl|GQ337064.1_cds_ACT99625.1_2 100.000 
aac(6')-33_1_GQ337064   lcl|JN596280.1_cds_AEZ05106.1_2 100.000 
aac(6')-aph(2'')_1_M13771       lcl|CP000029.1_cds_AAW54933.1_1550   100.000
aac(6')-aph(2'')_1_M13771       lcl|M13771.1_cds_AAA26865.1_1   100.000 
aac(6')-aph(2'')_1_M13771       lcl|FN433596.1_cds_CBI49941.1_2062      99.931
```

The desired output would be:

```
aac(3)-IIa_1_X51534     lcl|X51534.1_cds_CAA35913.1_1   100.000       
aac(3)-IIa_1_X51534     lcl|JQ364967.1_cds_AFI72859.1_82        99.768 
aac(3)-IIa_1_X51534     lcl|EU022315.1_cds_ABS70978.1_1 99.535 
aac(6')-33_1_GQ337064   lcl|GQ337064.1_cds_ACT99625.1_2 100.000 
aac(6')-33_1_GQ337064   lcl|JN596280.1_cds_AEZ05106.1_2 100.000 
aac(6')-aph(2'')_1_M13771       lcl|M13771.1_cds_AAA26865.1_1   100.000 
aac(6')-aph(2'')_1_M13771       lcl|CP000029.1_cds_AAW54933.1_1550   100.000
aac(6')-aph(2'')_1_M13771       lcl|FN433596.1_cds_CBI49941.1_2062      99.931
```

I move the matching line (in the first one, it's the X51534) to the top of the group. (It's not always the 2nd line in the group though.)  I can do using Perl, or in Bash the long way (with several loops).  However, I think there should be a neat solution (perhaps using awk)?  I've tried a number of awk solutions using associative arrays, but I can't crack this for some reason.  I have a habit of over-complicating my programs (working on that).  Any hints for me?

Comment: can you edit question to show your work, aka script ?

Comment: My script was about 10 lines long and didn't accomplish the end goal so I thought it would lengthen the post unnecessarily.  Since the awk comment below answers my question, I won't edit the post.  I knew there had to be an awk solution but I couldn't figure it out.  I'm sorry I couldn't add more in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{n=split($1,a,"_"); print ($2~a[n]) "\t" $0}' | 
  sort -k2,2 -k1,1r -s | cut -f2-
```

Comment: Wow, this is so cool!  I ran each command separately to figure out what they all do.  As I said I love to over-complicate things - I had a long script but I just knew there was an easier way with awk! I know all these commands but I didn't think to put them together like this.  This is what I love about writing code!  Thank you so much, this is a great learning experience that will help me write more efficient code going forward.